# Multiple filters on indexed field

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite

Consider two queries:

```
SELECT Log.Key, Time, Filter.Name, Text, Blob
FROM Log
JOIN Filter ON FilterKey = Filter.Key
WHERE FilterKey IN (1)
ORDER BY Log.Key
LIMIT @limit
OFFSET @offset
```

and

```
SELECT Log.Key, Time, Filter.Name, Text, Blob
FROM Log
JOIN Filter ON FilterKey = Filter.Key
WHERE FilterKey IN (1,2)
ORDER BY Log.Key
LIMIT @limit
OFFSET @offset
```

Difference is `IN(1)` vs `IN(1,2)`. Problem: second query is ~50 times slower (on 3 Gb database it's `0.2s` vs `13.0s`)!

I know what `WHERE FilterKey IN (1,2)` is equal to `WHERE FilterKey = 1 OR FilterKey = 2`. It seems what only single filter works well with index. Why?

How to increase performance of second query (to use multiple conditions)?

---

Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Filter (Key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT)
CREATE TABLE Log (Key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Time DATETIME, FilterKey INTEGER, Text TEXT, Blob BLOB)
CREATE INDEX FilterKeyIndex on Log(FilterKey)
```

Comment: Which SQLite version?

Comment: @CL, How can I see that? In the beginning of `.sqlite` file there is `SQLite format 3` (I tagged question as [tag:sqlite3]).

Comment: Of the library you're using to execute the query, not of the file.

Comment: @CL, `System.Data.SQLite` 1.0.102 (latest stable as for now).

Comment: That would be SQLite 3.13.0.

Answer (score 1):

The `FilterKeyIndex` stores not only the `FilterKey` values but also the `rowid` of the actual table to be able to find the corresponding row. The index is sorted over both columns.

In the first query, when reading all index entries whose `FilterKey` is one, in order, the `rowid` values also are in order. That `rowid` is the same as `Log.Key`, so it is not necessary to do any further sorting.

In the second query, the `Log.Key` values come from two index runs, so there is no guarantee that they are sorted, so the database has to sort all results rows before it can return the first one.

---

To speed up the second query, you would have to read all the `Log` rows in the order of the `Key` column, i.e., scan the table without looking up any `Log` rows in the index. Either drop `FilterKeyIndex`, or use `... FROM Log NOT INDEXED JOIN ...`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the reason. Is there an easy way to make second query faster (e.g. by changing structure)?